# Accidentally deleted local folders when trying to remove from git repository. Unable to retrieve.

Tags: git

Okay so I'm in a bit of a pickle. I just got started with git, so I'm very much a noob at the moment.

I created a repository in a local folder and through terminal I was able to add and commit files to it. As I was transferring these to my github, I received an error that said some files were too big and some were just unable to go so it failed. Smart me thought that I'd delete one of the folders that may be causing the issue, so I used `git rm -r -- <folder>` to remove it. That worked, but it also removed it locally as well, so I panicked because I've just lost an entire folder of stuff.

Doing `git status` showed that the files of that folder were marked 'deleted' but their deletion hadn't been committed yet which meant my next task was to resurrect them. I tried a few things that I found on other similar posts, but the short of it is that I can't find them anymore, they are no longer listed in `git_status` (although I never committed them) and I have no idea if I'll ever see them again.

I've tried `git checkout`, `git revert`, and I've tried checking deleted files with `git log --diff-filter=D --summary` and `git ls-files --deleted`, but it's as if these files never existed.

My first commit included all my files, but I can't seem to get back to that either.

Any ideas on how I can get my files back?

Comment: Why did you `rm` if you did not intend to rm ?

Comment: @gogaz because `git rm --cached` actually would reflect what the OP intended to do (remove from staging area). This works for any other type of committed file, but I don't think it works for deletion. So I really understand the confusion here.

Comment: @rubenvb that's right, cached was what I intended to do, but I only realised my mistake after making it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not committed yet. You can get back the last commit with

```
git checkout HEAD
```

Be sure to avoid using the following flags without first understanding what they do: `-f` or `--force`. These flags permit Git to destroy data. So don’t use them unless you’re sure you want to do that, and know what data you will be deleting.

Comment: Is there any way I can get back to my very first commit?

Comment: HEAD is a special name which refers to the commit which is currently checked out. You can look at a list of commits with `git log`, and you’ll see each commit named with some hexadecimal like "commit 12ab34de....". You can run `git checkout 12ab34de` to check out commit 12ab34de, and then you can `git checkout master` to go back to the tip of the branch.